# hardware scan codes doesn't match in c function keybd_event

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to learn how to simulate key strokes in my Win32 program, and I think I understand how the syntax goes, but there's something I don't quite understand: there's seems to be a dissonance between the virtual key code (1st argument) and the hardware scan code (2nd argument). Look at [this code for example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event)

```
keybd_event( VK_NUMLOCK,
                  0x45,
                  KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,
                  0 );
```

Numlock key is not 0x45, but rather 0x90, as seen on the table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), so what's the deal?

Comment: No, you linked to a table that only lists virtual key codes.  Try [this one](http://www.philipstorr.id.au/pcbook/book3/scancode.htm).

Comment: @HansPassant it seems that the link is broken ):, but the it seems that the value under each virtual key code is hex

Comment: You are attempting this on Windows -- right? A majority of the documentation as MSDN is implementation defined for DOS/Windows only. (like `conio.h`, etc...). If you are not on Windows, you will quickly run into this difference. Don't get me wrong, the MSDN documentation is an excellent reference, but understand most applies only to that OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VK_NUMLOCK` - is [virtual key code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes). `0x45` - is a scan code for this key.

You can think of a scan code as a hardware identifier for a keyboard key. Modern HID API use HID Usages for the same intention but Windows APIs get stuck to old i8042 scan codes from PS/2 era and IBM PC. FYI [here is mapping tables between HID Usages and scan codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#scan-codes) that is done by Windows HID keyboard driver.

Virtual key code is used in Win32 APIs to identify which key was pressed.

Keyboard layout is responsible for doing `scanCode`->`vkCode`->`character` conversion. So on one PC you can install several layouts that will do these mappings. [Here is the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/windows-keyboard-layouts).

You don't have to hardcode scan codes in your program code since they can depend on keyboard layout. For example in [US QWERTY keyboard layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdus_7) scan code `0x10` is mapped to the `VK_Q` but in [French AZERTY keyboard layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdfr) same scan code `0x10` is mapped to the `VK_A`.

You can use [MapVirtualKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyw) API to do reverse `vkCode`->`scanCode` mapping and get the scan code (possibly with extended part to provide `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` accordingly):

```cpp
BYTE vk = VK_NUMLOCK;
WORD scanCode = LOWORD(MapVirtualKey(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX));

INPUT input = {};
input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input.ki.wVk = vk;
input.ki.wScan = LOBYTE(scanCode);
input.ki.dwFlags = HIBYTE(scanCode) == 0xE0 ? KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY : 0;

SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Also note that `keybd_event` is deprecated and it is recommended to use `SendInput` API instead. Also, it is better to call `SendInput` with key press and key release in one call (provide an array) - this way you will be sure that this batch will be processed by a Win32 window without interference from a real keyboard.

Comment: Where does one find this "*MapVirtualKey API to do reverse vkCode->scanCode mapping*"? Is it standard C or something implementation defined by windows? If it is, how would that work for non-windows systems?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it is Win32 API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapvirtualkeyw. Other systems do not tied to the i8042 scan codes and usually have ability to get HID Usage value for a key press - that can be used for the same purpose.

Comment: Actually AFAIK C API do not have such thing as keyboard input - you can only work with i/o file/device objects that contains character strings like `\n` for Enter key etc. Keyboard input is platform-specific stuff.

Comment: Okay, good reference. You may want to make clear that is what you answer applies to. Nothing wrong with it, but the question is a bit unclear or at least ambiguous on what environment they are working in. Any yes you are right, most terminal and key handling will be implementation defined.

Comment: I made edits to the OP question. It will be visible after approve.